# Blue screen while using windows even in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have this problem with Windows 7 after I detected and cleaned up some viruses with Nod32.

```
problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1065

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   50
  BCP1: FFFFF900CA578010
  BCP2: 0000000000000000
  BCP3: FFFFF9600019619B
  BCP4: 0000000000000002
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\060312-34195-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Fatemeh\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-51215-0.sysdata.xml
```

How can I prevent these crashes?

Comment: Have you recently made any hardware changes?

Comment: At what point does it crash? During startup? Before login? During login? After login? While you're using it? Basically, what's the last action before crash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking down random BSOD on windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/130786/tracking-down-random-bsod-on-windows-7)

Comment: or this one....http://superuser.com/questions/276018/bsod-in-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit

Answer (score 0):

BSoD/Stop Code 50 is "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA", and is usually a hardware (or corrupted driver) fault, or in some instances can be caused by a [Rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) infection (See Microsoft KB article "[The computer may automatically restart, or you may receive a "serious error" message or a Stop error message in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=894278)").

Assuming you've added no hardware recently, and since you say you just cleaned multiple infections off of the system, I'd say additional scans for a rootkit are in order.

For more info on removing Rootkits (including utlitiies you can try) check out these related questions:

- [Which rootkit cleaner do you recommend for Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/14750/which-rootkit-cleaner-do-you-recommend-for-windows-xp)
- [Is there a way to find rootkits on 64-bit Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/49654/is-there-a-way-to-find-rootkits-on-64-bit-windows-7)
- [Anti-rootkit tool for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/271952/anti-rootkit-tool-for-windows-7)

Personally, I (currently) like [Kaspersky's TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363) as my main AntiRootkit utility.

Some good info on Stop 50, and posbbile causes, can be found here: [FaultWire Stop 50](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-fatal_error/PAGE-FAULT-IN-NONPAGED-AREA-0x00000050-*1095.html?order=votes)

Plus you also may want to check out [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an unpleasant answer, but after (obviously unsuccessfully) cleaning *some* viruses, this system cannot be consiedered clean. Unless you exactly know, where these "viruses" (which are probably not just the nowadays rare viruses but rather other malware) came from and what they did, you will barely be able to reliably clean your system. Such crashes are a commonly caused by rootkits still being active on the system failing to work properly due to partial removal of the malware.

The fastest and only reliable way to get rid of an infection is to backup data, format the system partition and reinstall your OS. Even if you had given much more details about the found malware and your removal attempt, nobody would not be able to clean your system reliably. I even doubt your bsod could be fixed this way.